# Live Streaming in android application

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I want to create an **android app based on Live Streaming**.But I have not found any way to achieve this.

I have got the following points.

a.I have to record the video using my phone camera.
b.At the same time I have to use a streaming encoder to compress the video signals.
c.Send them to distribution server.
d.then the end user can see the video using any app or web server.

And all this should take place at the same time or minimal time.

Am I Correct or I need some more information?????And most Important how can I achieve all these things.Please guys help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `PreviewCallback` to get the camera preview frames.

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                 //Send data to the server and call addCallbackBuffer(data) once data is used
                 camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
               }
        });
```

Use [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) for getting audio frames. For local storing of video, use FFMEG or [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html). You may need to encode the audio/video before sending/storing. This can be acheived by using 
[MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html).

Comment: can you please send me code.Actually I need a guidance to do this